# Image in Telerik Radgrid EditCommandColumn doesn't match EditImageUrl

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a detail table within a Telerik Radgrid that needs to allow inline editing. Everything in the grid works, except for the images displayed for Edit, Update, and Cancel operations aren't displaying. Instead they appear to be generic images.

The only link I was able to find regarding this issue is [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/editimageurl-in-detailtable) but the instructions didn't resolve my issue. This is the grid displaying the incorrect images:

```
                    <radG:GridTableView runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames="sysId" HierarchyLoadMode="ServerOnDemand"
                        GridLines="None" Name="RadGrid1" EditMode="InPlace" Width="100%" Height="75%" >
                        <EditFormSettings>
                            <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" ButtonType="ImageButton" EditImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnEdit.gif"
                                UpdateImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnSaveSM.gif" CancelImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnCancelSM.gif"
                                UpdateText="Save" InsertText="Save" InsertImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnSaveSM.gif">
                            </EditColumn>
                        </EditFormSettings>
                        <Columns>
                            <radG:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"
                                ButtonType="ImageButton" EditImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnEdit.gif">
                                <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                            </radG:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

The correct icons should look like this: [image: correct grid icons]

But the generic ones that appear show this: 
[image: incorrect grid icons]

I know the paths are correct, because they are the same as the images used in other non-detail grids I have in the site. It's not a huge issue as it functions correctly, but it is definitely ugly and pretty frustrating.

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I should have clarified that I tried using the same work present in the owner table's GridEditCommandColumn for the DetailTable which I'm showing now:

```
                   <radG:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn" UpdateText="Save" InsertText="Save"
                        ButtonType="ImageButton" InsertImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnSaveSM.gif"
                        UpdateImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnSaveSM.gif" CancelImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnCancelSM.gif"
                        EditImageUrl="~/APP_THEMES/MASTERPAGE/btnEdit.gif">
                        <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                    </radG:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply your images to the `GridEditCommandColumn`:

```
                    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"
                        ButtonType="ImageButton" EditImageUrl="~/images/icon_16x16.png" 
                        UpdateImageUrl="~/images/icon_16x16.png" CancelImageUrl="~/images/icon_16x16.png"
                        UpdateText="Save" InsertText="Save" InsertImageUrl="~/images/icon_16x16.png">
                        <ItemStyle Width="5%" />
                    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned that I had done this first, and my inability to get it to work is what drove me to use the telerik forum answer. When I get in to work I will edit the question to include it.

Comment: I posted what worked for me when testing. I hope you will resolve it, then you can post an answer and accept it :) BTW, try upgrading to the latest version, it does make sense to do that (often). Doing so may even resolve your issue in case you are using an old one and there has been a bug.

Comment: At our company we will be upgrading to the latest version this summer (we're still using one from '08) but I'm sure this would work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @strongbad1441 i hope it will. Good luck